# Authorization problem with rest api node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, postman

I have node.js package which uses rest api in ubuntu. When I login, this server (node package) gives me a token in json body. So when I want to do something (any request) in server I am using this token. But there is an error when I try to compare the token server gave with login and the token that client send to server.

The code to get token from the server:

```
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{ 
    const name = req.body.name;
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log("Login request by "+name+" with password: "+password);
    if(name == "asdasd" && password == "asdadsad"){
      console.log("Auth succesful");
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          user: name,
          password: password
        },
        process.env.JWT_KEY,
        {
          expiresIn: "1h"
        }
      )
      return res.status(200).json({
        message:"Auth succesful",
        token: token
      });
    }else {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message:"Auth failed :("
      })
    }
})
```

The code to make request with the given token:

```
router.post('/add',checkAuth,(req,res,next)=>{ 
    console.log('haha');
    const { 
        fname, mname, lname, birthdate, created, updated, sex, place, title_id
        } = req.body
    pool.query(`INSERT INTO users (
        fname, mname, lname, birthdate, created, updated, sex, place, title_id
        ) VALUES ($1, $2,$3, $4,$5, $6,$7, $8,$9)`, [
        fname, mname, lname, birthdate, created, updated, sex, place, title_id
        ], (error, result) => {
      if (error) {throw error}
      res.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${result.insertId}`)
    })
})
```

The code mentioned as checkAuth above:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req,res,next) =>{
    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization, process.env.JWT_KEY);
        req.userData = decoded;
        next();
    }catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
        });
    }
}
```

nodemon.json file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "JWT_KEY": "secret"
    }
}
```

This is the json response from the server I got when I connect to server with postman or with android studio:

```
{
    "message": "Auth failed"
}
```

This is the result of consol.log(process.env);

```
Object {ALLUSERSPROFILE: "C:\ProgramData", AMD_ENTRYPOINT: "vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHos…", APPDATA: "C:\Users\aydogan\AppData\Roaming", APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL: "true", CommonProgramFiles: "C:\Program Files\Common Files", …}
check-auth.js:6
[[StableObjectId]]:2
ALLUSERSPROFILE:"C:\ProgramData"
AMD_ENTRYPOINT:"vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess"
APPDATA:"C:\Users\aydogan\AppData\Roaming"
APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL:"true"
CommonProgramFiles:"C:\Program Files\Common Files"
CommonProgramFiles(x86):"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"
CommonProgramW6432:"C:\Program Files\Common Files"
COMPUTERNAME:"AYDOGAN"
ComSpec:"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
DriverData:"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData"
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING:"Internet Explorer"
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING:"Default"
HOMEDRIVE:"C:"
HOMEPATH:"\Users\aydogan"
IntelliJ IDEA:"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5\bin;"
LOCALAPPDATA:"C:\Users\aydogan\AppData\Local"
LOGONSERVER:"\\AYDOGAN"
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS:"8"
OneDrive:"C:\Users\aydogan\OneDrive"
OneDriveConsumer:"C:\Users\aydogan\OneDrive"
```

JWT_KEY seems undefined, I can see it with debug.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Do you use Express.js as well? Also can you share your main js file

Comment: Check what does ` process.env` console looks like. And shouldn't nodemon config file be `nodemon.json`

Comment: I don't use Express.js. It's already nodemon.json, sorry for inconvinience and I add process.env to above @ambianBeing. And thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: is it working via postman??

Comment: Only chechAuth has problem. All other (that I didn't shared) is working well via Postman and Android Studio and React.js. @sultania23 Also chechAuth is working but completely wrong

Comment: do you have .env file and dotenv package installed?

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: no I don't have .env file nor dotenv package installed. @onuriltan

Comment: I solved the problem. It is about Postgresql. I was trying to send string instead of char. I'm  sorry. But I was very nervous, There was no hope no solution, so I did write here the most suspicious parts of the code here. Anyway thanks a lot, I'm sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tying to get the JWT_KEY from environment via "process.env" but you did not set any environment variable for JWT_KEY.

You need to **create .env file inside the root of the project** and and put JWT_KEY there like `JWT_KEY=******` instead of nodemon.js file, also you need to install dotenv package via `npm install dotenv`and use it inside your main file as

**index.js**

```js
// Read Environment Variables Config
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

...
```

**.env**

```js
JWT_KEY=23489sgher8t238ifjk
```

This way you can get the JWT_KEY via process.env. Also if the repo is public I suggest not to push .env file to repository and keep it local to protect jwt key.